# Point aws cloudfront traffic to aws fargate api on same url

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-fargate

I have a node js api running aws fargate and i connected it to applicaiton load balancer
and it is on this link http://test-load-balancer-example.eu-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/api/data
(The api needs to be public because it will be used for an app)

And

I have the frontend react app on a s3 bucket and it is connected to cloudfront and it is on this link https://d109andj8k4fg5.cloudfront.net/
(The frontend will talk to the same api)

Now my plan is to have the api on the same cloudfront domain like this:

```
   - frontend : https://d109andj8k4fg5.cloudfront.net/
   - backend : https://d109andj8k4fg5.cloudfront.net/api/data
```

How should i do this ?
Should i buy a new domain and then do it or is it possible to do it on the cloudfront domain?

This is the develompent enviroment so the way it is currently is fine
but i want it like that on the production enviroment so i need to know how to do it

help is appericated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should i do this ?

Simply add the load balancer URL as a second origin in your CloudFront distribution, and [configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern) CloudFront to send all `/api/*` requests to that origin.

> Should i buy a new domain and then do it or is it possible to do it on the cloudfront domain?

You can do this with the CloudFront domain. Adding a custom domain isn't going to affect how CloudFront makes request to the origin servers.